# Webscraping Elephant Data in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to webscrape a page (e.g. "my_website.html") - the webpage looks something like this:

[image]

And the source code for this page looks something like this:

```
<div class="one_third">
<strong>my_name_1.</strong><br />
address_1<br />
city_1<br />
phone_1<br />
<a href="website1.com" target="_blank">Website</a>
</div>
<div class="one_third">
<strong>my_name_2</strong><br />
address_2<br />
city_2<br />
phone_2<br />
<a href="website2.com">Website</a>
</div>
<div class="one_third last">
<strong>my_name_2</strong><br />
address_2,<br />
city_2<br />
phone_2
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="hr hr1" style='margin:20px !important;'></div>
<div class="one_third">
<strong>my_name_3</strong><br />
address_3<br />
city_3<br />
phone_3<br />
<a href="website3.com" target="_blank">Website</a>
</div>
<div class="one_third">
<strong>my_name_4</strong><br />
address_4,<br />
city_4<br />
phone_4
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the following information into a data frame - this would look something like this:

```
     name   address   city   phone
1 my_name_1 address_1 city_1 phone_1
2 my_name_2 address_2 city_2 phone_2
3 my_name_3 address_3 city_3 phone_3
4 my_name_4 address_4 city_4 phone_4
```

I found this tutorial (https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-in-r-rvest/) and tried to do this:

```
library(rvest)
simple <- read_html("my_website.html")
```

Then, I tried different combinations of the following command to try and extract the names, addresses, cities and phone numbers:

```
 simple %>%
    html_nodes("strong") %>%
    html_text()

 simple %>%
    html_nodes("bold") %>%
    html_text()

simple %>%
    html_nodes("br") %>%
    html_text()

simple %>%
    html_nodes(".br") %>%
    html_text()

simple %>%
    html_nodes("p")
```

But so far, none of this is working - But the addresses are not pulling.

**Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?**

Thanks!

Comment: Web scraping is entirely dependent on the specifics of the website in question. I appreciate the effort you have put into the reproducible example, but quite often the issue is that the website is dynamic and needs to be scraped in a different way. Are you able to share the url and actual data you are trying to scrape?

Comment: @ Allan Cameron: Thank you for your reply! I was avoiding posting the actual website because it contains real names that I thought might be a problem - but here is the website: https://www.dentistdirectorycanada.ca/british-columbia/

Comment: I made some progress! b = simple %>%
    html_nodes("div") %>%
    html_text()

Comment: c = as.list(b) - from here, at least the addresses have pulled - but the format is really messy ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a head start:

```
library(rvest)

url<-"mywebsite.html"
page <-read_html(url)

#find the div tab of class=one_third
b = page %>% html_nodes("div.one_third") 

listanswer <- b %>% html_text() %>% strsplit("\\n")
```

"listanswer" has a vector for each entry. Now comes the had part, each address can have 1 to 3 elements for the name(s) and at the end may or may not have a phone number or website.  I think you can go through this list of vectors pick out the city, contains "Vancouver" the element before is the street address the element after, contains "P:" is the phone, and everything before the address are the names.

Good luck.

Comment: @ Dave2e: thank you so much for your answer! Just one request - can you please replace the actual url with some generic name (e..g https://www.mywebsite.com) for privacy reasons? thank you so much!